# Get Singleton FactoryClass in extension method parameter

Tags: c#, asp.net-core

I have a factory class whose contents are auto-generated code.  It looks something like this:

```
public class FactoryClass
{
    private IConfiguration _config;
    private FactoryClass(IConfiguration config) =>_config = config;

    public static FactoryClass Create(IConfiguration config) => new FactoryClass(config);
    
    public class GeneratedSpecialObjectClass
    {
        public GeneratedSpecialObjectClass()
        {
            ...
        }

        public GeneratedSpecialObjectClass Create() => ...

    }
    ...
}
```

I've added to my IServiceCollection as a Singleton

```
services.AddSingleton(FactoryClass.Create(configuration))
```

Now I'm going through a bunch of extension methods that need to use the `FactoryClass`.

Example:

```
public static GeneratedSpecialObjectClass GetSpecialObjectClass(this SpecialObjectValidatorResult result, FactoryClass factoryClass)
{
    if (result.GeneratedProducts.Length > 0)
        factoryClass.GeneratedSpecialObjectClass.Create();
}
```

Do I need to pass the `FactoryClass` class into each extension method as a parameter, or is it possible to get it some other way?

Comment: What extension methods are you talked? Show some example

Comment: This probably breaks all kinds of rules but... https://www.davidezoccarato.cloud/resolving-instances-with-asp-net-core-di-in-static-classes/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's a lot that's coupled together. If `FactoryClass` gets passed to an extension, that means whatever calls the extension must have an instance of `FactoryClass`. Something somewhere will need to create an instance of `FactoryClass`, and it will need an instance of `IConfiguration`. All this has to happen before you can even call the extension method.

You're question is about the extension method, though. You said it needs an instance of the factory class. But what is it using it for? It's using it to call a `Create()` method and get back an instance of `GeneratedSpecialObjectClass`. So really what it needs is a function that returns a `GeneratedSpecialObjectClass`.

In that case, here's my recommendation. Do not pass your factory class to the extension. Instead of having a `FactoryClass` argument in the extension, have a `Func<GeneratedSpecialObjectClass>` argument. That is, a function that returns `GeneratedSpecialObjectClass`.

Why? If whatever calls the extension has an instance of `FactoryClass`, it can pass just the method instead of passing the whole class. (why is that better? I'll get to it.)

That is, instead of this:

```
public static GeneratedSpecialObjectClass GetSpecialObjectClass(
    this SpecialObjectValidatorResult result, 
    FactoryClass factoryClass)
{
    if (result.GeneratedProducts.Length > 0)
        factoryClass.GeneratedSpecialObjectClass.Create();
}
```

do this:

```
public static GeneratedSpecialObjectClass GetSpecialObjectClass(
    this SpecialObjectValidatorResult result, 
    Func<GeneratedSpecialObjectClass> factoryMethod)
{
    if (result.GeneratedProducts.Length > 0)
        factoryMethod();
}
```

(I don't get the part where you're calling `Create()` but not assigning it anything. But executing that method will return a `GeneratedSpecialObjectClass`, so you could assign it to a variable.)

Now the code that calls the extension wouldn't pass the factory class. It would pass the method. That would look like this:

```
result.GetSpecialObjectClass(factoryClass.Create);
```

Notice that I'm passing `Create`, not `Create()`. I'm not calling the method. I'm passing it as an argument. The extension method gets a reference to the function - not the class - and can call the function.

Why am I going through all of this and recommending that you pass a function instead of passing the entire `FactoryClass`? Because I suspect that at some point what's going on with that factory class is going to get too complex and you'll want to change it.

If all of those extension methods take `FactoryClass` as an argument and then you change how you create a class - maybe you no longer want to create that factory class - then you'll have to change all of those extension methods.

If you pass `Func<GeneratedSpecialObjectClass>`, you can use the `Create` method from your factory. But you can also pass any other method with the same signature - any other method with no parameters that returns `GeneratedSpecialObjectClass`. You're no longer locked in. You can change the code that calls the extension without changing the extension.

It's a small detail, but that will keep more of your code from becoming coupled to something else, especially something which is very likely to change.

Comment: You're right, I could pass a function instead of the entire factory class, but that would still necessitate me instantiating the FactoryClass outside the extension method in order to pass in the function,right?  That means that I need to instantiate it for every class that has extension methods that use it (even those that are purely data-oriented).  For context, this is being used for a list of error codes atm.  What I'm hearing is that adding it as a singleton doesn't give access to this FacotryClass in other places - or have I misunderstood something?

Comment: Correct. You still have to create the factory class. You were doing that anyway, so I recommended changing what you pass. If you're trying to solve having to create `FactoryClass` over and over, that's a great problem to solve. It's a different one from what I answered. It's actually a way more important question. But it's not clearly spelled out, and the answer is completely different.

Comment: The larger answer is that you might want to stop depending on extension methods. A static class either a) doesn't have something you don't pass to it as an argument, or b) usually creates and shares one instance. Whatever the classes are that depend on the extension methods, you might want to use dependency injection and inject an interface or delegate. But that's impossible to get into without seeing more of the picture, like what these classes are. I highly recommend looking into dependency injection. I think you'll find what you're looking for.